# My Flask server on Pythonanywhere.com not works at my Ionic app

Tags: javascript, python, android, typescript, flask

I have a problem, when giv my Falsk py to cloud serve phytonanywhere.com works at Hi, I have a problem, when I giv my Falsk py to cloud serve phytonanywhere.com works at Chrome, but not works at app.

This is my flask_app.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify,request
from posts import posts


app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    lang = request.headers.get("Accept-Language", 'sk')[:2]

    p = list(map (lambda post: translate(post, lang), posts))

    return jsonify(p)


def translate(post, lang):
    translation = next (t for t in post['translations'] if t['locale'] == lang)

    return {
        "id": post ['id'],
        "title": translation ['title'],
        "description": translation ['description'],
        "image": post['image'],
}
```

Works at Chrome, I see this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1kET.png)

And my app code is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts2',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.scss'],
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  posts:any = [];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 

  ngOnInit() {
    

    const lang = localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'sk';
    
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept-Language': lang
    })   
  
  
    this.http.get('http://miki83.pythonanywhere.com/', {
      headers: headers
    }).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log();
      this.posts = data;
       });
  }

}
```

How is problem? I paste the cloud Url to app.

Comment: Could you clafiry what is working and what is not working?  Providing some error messages that you get would also be helpful.

Comment: when I run my application real on Android Studio Drive then I have empty screen

Comment: Look in the developer tools for the browser to see if you're getting javascript errors.